# Powershell - ensuring uppercase drive letters

Tags: powershell, range, character

I am logging into the VM and manually initializing the newly added disk partitioning it and creating volume. 
My question is : I want to use upper case for drive letters. 
I have checked inside variable.

```
e.g ([Char]$DiskArray[$DiskArrayIndex])
d
```

script :

```
$DiskArray = 100..122 # D to Y
$DiskArrayIndex = 0

$Disks = Get-Disk |  Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' 

Foreach  ($D in $Disks) {
        $D | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru | 
        New-Partition -DriveLetter ([Char]$DiskArray[$DiskArrayIndex]) -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | 
        Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "datadisk" -Confirm:$false

        $DiskArrayIndex+=1
}
```

LAST UPDATE :

```
$DiskArray = 100..122 # D to Y
$DiskArrayIndex = 0

$Disks = Get-Disk |  Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' 

Foreach  ($D in $Disks) {
        $D | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT -PassThru | 
        New-Partition -DriveLetter ([char]([string][char]$DiskArray[$DiskArrayIndex]).ToUpper()) -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | 
        Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "datadisk" -Confirm:$false

        $DiskArrayIndex+=1
}
```

Comment: Upper case letters are from 65 to 90. Not from 100 to 122!!!

Comment: Oops ok man I assuming 65 equal `A` I will use this `$DiskArray = 68..90 # D to Y`

Comment: Use `$DiskArray = 68..89` for _uppercase_ letters D to Y, or get uppercase on the fly as `[char]([string][char]$DiskArray[$DiskArrayIndex]).ToUpper()`.

Comment: @JosefZ thanks again I have updated my code. am I correct ?

Comment: You're still using `100..122` !?!? Why make it more complex than needed?  And if you want to know if you're correct you should run your code and see what happens. ;-)

Comment: Just use cast operator instead of numbers:  `$DiskArray = [byte][char]'D' .. [byte][char]'Y'   # D to Y` and you wan't go wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>To summarize and complement the helpful information from the comments on the question:</sup>

**tl;dr**

Windows PowerShell:

```
# Stores array of strings 'D', 'E', ..., 'Y' in $DiskArray
[string[]] $DiskArray = [char[]] (68..89)
$DiskArrayIndex = 0

# ... inside `for` loop:
$DiskArray[$DiskArrayIndex++] # -> 'D' in 1st iteration, then 'E', ...
```

PowerShell [Core, v6+]:

```
# In PowerShell [Core] you can use characters as endpoints as well.
[string[]] $DiskArray = 'D'..'Y'

# ... same as above
```

If you don't want to hard-code the endpoints of the range operation (`68..89`), you can derive them from the characters directly:
`[string[]] $DiskArray = [char[]] ([int] [char] 'D' .. [int] [char] 'Y')`

---

**In *PowerShell* [Core, v6+], you can directly use *characters* as endpoints for `..`**, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-):

```
PS> 'D'..'F'  # outputs an array of [char] instances
D
E
F
```

In cases where `[string]`s are expected, PowerShell automatically converts `[char]` instances to `[string]`s, so there is no strict need to explicitly convert the resulting array of `[char]` instances to strings, but if you want to do so, simply cast / type-constrain to `[string[]]`, as shown at the top.

---

**In *Windows PowerShell*, `..` only supports `[int]` endpoints** (which includes numbers that can be *converted to* `[int]`).

Therefore, you must:

- determine the *Unicode code points* ("ASCII value") of the endpoints of your character range:

  - To that end, cast the character of interest first to `[char]`, and then to `[int]`:
  - `[int] [char] 'D'` -> `68`
  - `[int] [char] 'Y'` -> `89`
  - Note that the intermediate `[char]` cast is necessary, because PowerShell has no `[char]` literals; even a single character in single quotes such as `'D'` is a *string*, and casting a string to `[int]` tries to interpret the value of the string as a number rather than reporting the character's code point.
- express your range as a range of code points:

  - `68..89`
  - You can also *combine* this step with the one above:

    - `[int] [char] 'D' .. [int] [char] 'Y'`
- convert the resulting array of `[int]` instances back to `[char]` instances with a `[char[]]` cast, and optionally thereafter to `[string]` instances with a `[string[]]` cast:

  - `[char[]] (68..89)` -> `[char] 'D', [char] 'E', ..., [char] 'Y'`

    - Note the need for `(...)` around the range operation; due to [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence), the `[char[]]` would otherwise only apply to the first endpoint, not to the result of the whole range operation.
  - `[string[]] [char[]] (68..89)` creates *string* array `'D', 'E', ..., 'Y'`

    - The reason the intermediate `[char[]]` cast is needed is that a direct `[string[]]` cast from an `[int[]]` array would simply create the string representations of the integers; e.g., `68` would become `"68"` rather than being interpreted as a code point.

Answer (score 2):

It could be just me, but I don't see why you would not do something simple like

```
$DiskArray = 'DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'.ToCharArray()
```

and use it like this:

```
$DiskArrayIndex = 0
foreach($D in $Disks) {
    ...
    New-Partition -DriveLetter $DiskArray[$DiskArrayIndex++] -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize
    ...
}
```

This will save you from doing all those type casts. Also, by using syntax `$DiskArrayIndex++`, the index is automatically increased, so you can remove `$DiskArrayIndex+=1`